# am trying to incorporate javascript into my html, the first method works perfect,but the second dosent work at all, but why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, simplebar

am trying to incorporate simplebar into my html, the first method works perfect,but the second dosent work at all, but why? I think they are the same code.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div data-simplebar style="background-color: rgb(160, 158, 158); width: 400px; height: 150px;">
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

As below, am using javascript to add attributes and values to the original html code, by using the Chrome inspect mode, u can see the second method doesnt work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute("data-simplebar", "init");
  let a = document.createElement('link'),
    doc;
  a.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  a.setAttribute("href", "https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.css");
  doc = document.head;
  doc.appendChild(a);
  let b = document.createElement('script'),
    dod;
  b.setAttribute("src", "https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js");
  dod = document.body;
  dod.appendChild(b);
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(160, 158, 158); width: 400px; height: 150px;">
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not exactly the same.

In the second example you are setting data-simplebar on the first div to have value "init".

But in your first snippet the data-simplebar is empty.

This snippet is your second one with the init replaced with nothing in the JS.

The result seems now to be the same as your first snippet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute("data-simplebar", "");
  let a = document.createElement('link'),
    doc;
  a.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  a.setAttribute("href", "https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.css");
  doc = document.head;
  doc.appendChild(a);
  let b = document.createElement('script'),
    dod;
  b.setAttribute("src", "https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js");
  dod = document.body;
  dod.appendChild(b);
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(160, 158, 158); width: 400px; height: 150px;">
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</div>
```